# SAS Proc Format Executing Without All Datetime Directives

Tags: format, sas

I have defined a datetime format with `%h %0M %0S` , but when it executes within my macro, the hour part is left out. Below is the (unedited) log from a stripped down macro using option mprint to demonstrate the issue.

Notice at the top of the log, where my macro is reprinted, the format my_fmt includes a "%h" ... but then below in the log when my_fmt is referenced, it is printed without "%h" in it, and then outputs a string with the hour part missing. I've tried with several different format names (including a random string) as well to make sure it's not conflicting with a pre-existing format. (using SAS 9.4 in case that matters).

```
18486  %macro myMacro(mydt);
18487
18488  %put &mydt;
18489  proc format; picture my_fmt low-high = "%0d-%b-%Y %h:%0M:%0S" (datatype=datetime); quit;
18490
18491      %*Comment;
18492      %let startDT_fmtd = %sysfunc(putn(&mydt, my_fmt.));
18493      %put &startDT_fmtd;
18494  %mend;
18495
18496  %*Useage example;
18497  %myMacro(1738144208.3);

1738144208.3
MPRINT(MYMACRO):   proc format;
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro B not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro Y not resolved.
MPRINT(MYMACRO):   picture my_fmt low-high = "%0d-%b-%Y %0M:%0S" (datatype=datetime);
NOTE: Format MY_FMT has been output.
MPRINT(MYMACRO):   quit;

NOTE: PROCEDURE FORMAT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.01 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds


29-JAN-2015 50:08
```

Comment: The default length may not be long enough for your string, have you tried specifying the length? 'Picture my_fmt (default=32)...'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried and that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Adding to my confusion, the format works in a clean editor window when not in a macro. But called even in this barest of macros, it doesn't.

Comment: Try single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: The log indicates that SAS is trying to treat %h, %m as macros. You can avoid this by using single quotes.

Comment: Yes, try single quotes. It's odd that you don't get a warning  about trying to invoke macro %h. And weird that MPRINT doesn't show the : before %0M. Then again, MPRINT is sometimes wonky. Curious if you check the format definition with 'proc format library=work fmtlib;' what it will show.

Comment: Thanks everyone, single quotes worked. I've been accustomed to ignoring that warning, as I see it often without having a problem. Like I said even this format worked outside a macro.

Comment: @Quentin, I defined two formats, with the only difference being the (format name) and double vs single quotes. I did this in a blank editor and in another editor within the macro above. When I ran the fmtlib statement you suggested, the two formats defined outside the macro were identical, and the two formats defined in the macro were not. Of the ones defined in the macro the one defined with double quotes was missing the %h. I wonder why that is.

Comment: Glad you got it solved. What do you get from `%put >>%h<<;` ?  If it shows >><< in the log, that would suggest you have a macro named H defined which returns a null value.

Comment: Hi Quentin, that seems like it was a good guess, but I'm just getting "apparent invocation of macro H not resolved" (for the string you suggested, including lowercase h)

Comment: Thanks for trying. This is very odd. I'll play with it next time I'm in front of SAS (probably tomorrow) and respond if I see anything interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log indicates that SAS is trying to treat %h, %m as macros. You can avoid this by using single quotes in your proc format.

Comment: Actually, %h is being treated as a %label, because it has a colon after it, i.e. %h: .  I added an answer below with details.  Agree with the solution of using single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

After some brute-force debugging, I realized the %h in your code is not being treated as a macro call. It is being treated as a %label statement (for %goto), **because there is a colon after it**.  This explains why it does not trigger a warning in your log and is not part of the generated code.

Here is a simplified example:

```
127  %macro test(dummy);
128    %put "%y %h:";
129  %mend;
130  %test()
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro Y not resolved.
"%y "
```

If you remove the colon, it works as expected:

```
131  %macro test(dummy);
132    %put "%y %h";
133  %mend;
134  %test()
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro Y not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro H not resolved.
"%y %h"
```

This shows the %h: label works for %goto:

```
167  %macro test(dummy);
168    %goto h;
169    %put I am skipped by goto;
170    %put "%y %h:";
171  %mend;
172  %test()
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro Y not resolved.
"%y "
```

Surprisingly (to me) I think that last example shows that a %GOTO label in the middle of a macro statement not only "works", it is the same as a %GOTO label at the beginning of the statement.

This also explains why the code works in open code (outside of a macro definition).  Outside of a macro, %h: cannot be interpreted as a %GOTO label, so the %h is interpreted as a macro invocation, and the colon is just text:

```
209  %put "%y %h:";
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro Y not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent invocation of macro H not resolved.
"%y %h:"
```

That said, @Reeza's solution of using single quotes is correct, as this prevents the %h: from being interpreted as a macro label.

Comment: Wild. Thanks a lot for looking into that more and tracking the fundamental issue down.

Comment: Hey Quentin, one last question. In my original format statement, there was a colon after %h but also after %0M. The %h wasn't read (or not how I intended it to be), but the %0M was. Do you understand why that is?

Comment: A %GOTO label must be a valid SAS name.  SAS names cannot begin with a number (0).  When the macro compiler sees a % sign followed by the number 0, it does not interpret it as a %label, or as a macro invocation.  It's just text.  So it works they way you want.  For the same reason, `%put %0M;` will not trigger a warning about macro 0M not resolving.  Note in your original log, you only got two warnings about %B and %Y not resolving.